# WIX: How to display variable in custom dialog box?

Tags: wix

I would like to display some variables in custom dialog box. For example I would like to inform users about a version number of a product beeing installed.

Header of  the main .wxs file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?define ProductVersion = 1.0.20.15?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
      <Product Id="*" 
               Name="BNS" 
               Language="1029" 
               Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
...
```

If  I try to add this Control tag to dialog box:

```
<Control Id="VersionNumber" Type="Text" X="20" Y="175" Width="290" Height="30" Transparent="yes" Text="$(var.ProductVersion)" NoPrefix="yes"/>
```

"Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.ProductVersion)'." error occurs when I try it to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make candle aware of this preprocessor variable. Use '-d' switch for this. For more information, type "candle" in console.